# VSCODE: jupyter adding interactive matplotlib plot %matplotlib widget not working interactively

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, widget

The following example doesn't work in VSCODE. It works (with %matplotlib notebook in a Jupyter notebook in a web browser though).

```
# creating 3d plot using matplotlib 
# in python
  
# for creating a responsive plot
# use %matplotlib widget in VSCODE
#%matplotlib widget
%matplotlib notebook
  
# importing required libraries
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
# creating random dataset
xs = [14, 24, 43, 47, 54, 66, 74, 89, 12,
      44, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
  
ys = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 3,
      5, 2, 4, 1, 8, 7, 0, 5]
  
zs = [9, 6, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 8, 7, 0, 1, 2, 
      3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
  
# creating figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
  
# creating the plot
plot_geeks = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, color='green')
  
# setting title and labels
ax.set_title("3D plot")
ax.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z-axis')
  
# displaying the plot
plt.show()
```

The result should be that you get a plot that can be e.g. rotated interactively using the mouse arrow.

In VSCODE one can click on the </> and a renderer is presented. Chosen is JupyterIPWidget Renderer. Other renderers show the plot but don't allow for interactive manipulation.

Also a warning appears:

```
/var/folders/kc/5p61t70n0llbn05934gj4r_w0000gn/T/ipykernel_22590/1606073246.py:23:
 MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Axes3D(fig) adding itself to the figure is 
deprecated since 3.4. Pass the keyword argument auto_add_to_figure=False 
and use fig.add_axes(ax) to suppress this warning. The default value of 
auto_add_to_figure will change to False in mpl3.5 and True values will
 no longer work in 3.6.  This is consistent with other Axes classes.
  ax = Axes3D(fig)
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is expected-- `%matplotlib notebook` is not supported in VS Code.  You should use `%matplotlib widget` instead.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Using-%25matplotlib-widget-instead-of-%25matplotlib-notebook,tk,etc

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the installation of `ipympl` for the selected kernel. So I had to run in a cell:

```
pip install ipympl
```